# Выбор языка для базы данных для фоток

Tags: любой-язык

Мне надо написать программу как база данных для фоток, с загрузкой их туда, с выставлением меток и последующим поиском по меткам. Сlarion не подходит, так как не получится показывать фотки в ней списком. Программа планируется локальная, так что PHP тоже не подходит. На каком лучше писать?

Answer (score 1):

Советую Python. Для работы с БД модуль sqlalchemy. Для графики pygtk.

Answer (score 1):

Выбор языка - сугубо личное.Я бы советовал прислушиваться к советам, но тем не менее не верить им слепо.Если подходить с точки зрения простоты - то подойдет и delphi pascal

Но все же я бы советовал Phyton, как и [@sercxjo](/users/1081/sercxjo)